# Was ist der Begriff für charakteristische Kombinationen wie »stinksauer«, »affenheiß«, »schweinekalt«?

Tags: single-word-request, adjective, compound, terminology

Bekanntlich gibt es in der deutschen Umgangssprache Lieblingskombinationen für einige Adjektive, wie  *stinksauer, affenheiß, schweinekalt* und so weiter.

Gibt es einen Begriff für diese aus Kombinationen bestehenden Adjektive, oder eine ausführliche Liste davon?   In welchen Dialekten bzw. seit wann gibt es die?   Gibt es so was nur im Deutschen?

Um die betreffende Kategorie genauer zu beschreiben:
Die Kombinationen ersetzen die Steigerungsform und dürfen daher mit *sehr* nicht weiter kombiniert werden.  So weit es mir jetzt einfällt, handelt es sich immer um [Nomen] + [Adjektiv].  Neue Kombinationen werden nicht gebildet, aber ab und zu gibt es mehrere charakteristische Kombinationen für ein Adjektiv.  Eine klare semantische Beziehung zu den selbständigen Nomen gibt es in der Regel nicht.

Comment: Ich glaube du meinst "Steigerungsform" ;) *Ver*steigern ist etwas anderes ;) Mir ist nicht bekannt, dass diese Adjektive einen besonderen Namen haben, aber sie sind alle umgangssprachlich und nicht für Schriftverkehr geeignet (und auch in Gesprächen nur in sehr informellen Umgebungen, ich würde z.B. mit Arbeitskollegen niemals so reden).

Comment: Sicher kann man so was wie *deutsche Adjektivskomposita* oder *adjektivische Zusammensetzungen* ausdenken, aber ich hätte gerne eine vollständige Liste, und dafür einen geeigneten Suchbegriff.

Comment: Ich habe den Oberbegriff *Nomen-Adjektiv-Komposita* [gefunden](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=969), aber der umfasst auch Wörter wie *weltweit*, *gebührenfrei*, *hautnah* und so weiter.

Comment: Ich würde diese Worte als "idiomatisch" bezeichnen (vgl. [Idiom auf Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom_(Spracheigent%C3%BCmlichkeit))), da sie eben je nach Region sich unterschiedlicher Beliebtheit erfreuen. Allerdings sind Idiome auch Dinge, die keine Nomen-Adjektiv-Komposita sind.

Comment: Stimmt alles, trotzdem ist *idiomatisches Nomen-Adjektiv-Kompositum* keine genaue Beschreibung weil ein wichtiges Merkmal der Bespielswörter die semantische Unlogik ist.

Comment: "Semantische Unlogik" ist durchaus bezeichnend für ein Idiom ;)

Comment: *So weit es mir jetzt einfällt, handelt es sich immer um [Nomen] + [Adjektiv]* – Was ist mit *stinksauer?*

Comment: Ja, gehört vielleich nicht.

Comment: Präfixoid und Halbpräfix sind auch relevante Begriffe die aber zu breit treffen.  (Im Wiktionary-Beitrag zu *Schwein* wird diese Steigerungsfunktion von *schweine-* als Präfixoid erwähnt.)

Comment: Das Wort "affenheiß" ist mir noch nicht untergekommen, nur die "Affenhitze". Auch "schweinekalt" ist mir nicht bekannt, noch nicht einmal als "Schweinekälte".

Comment: *schweinekalt* kennt der Duden, *affenheiß* nur Google.

Answer (score 10):

Es handelt sich um [*Präfix-Elative*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elativ). Sie sind idiomatisch, d.h. nur teilweise semantisch transparent, und treten auch in anderen indo-europäischen Sprachen auf.

(Eine Auflistung kenne ich nicht, aber die Konstruktion ist *sehr* gebräuchlich, und mir fällt für fast jedes gebräuchliche Adjektiv mindestens ein wortspezifisches Steigerungspräfix ein: riesengroß, winzigklein, eiskalt, siedendheiß, uralt, brandneu, taghell, stockdunkel, schneeweiß, pechschwarz, turmhoch, bettelarm, steinreich... erst bei "laut" und "leise" muß ich passen.)

Comment: Also mit Deiner Liste als Inspiration fällen mir ein Paar aus dem Englischen schon ein: *brand new*, *beet red*, *pitch black*... Und ich habe nachgeschaut, Shakespeare hat *fire-new* benutzt.  Trotzdem sagt mein Sprachgefühlt dass es etwas anders ist und dass wir diese Sorte noch genauer bezeichnen könnten, denn die Beispiele bei https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elativ passen nicht ins Schema.

Comment: Bei "laut" und "leise" hilft das Tierreich: Ich kann ja auch nichts dafür, aber mir fällt dazu "schweinelaut" und "sauleise" ein. Warum es umgekehrt nicht so gut geht, weiss ich leider auch nicht.

Comment: @PerlDog: Beide Ausdrücke habe ich noch nie gehört. Vielleicht ist das regional unterschiedlich?

Comment: @celtschk Das kann gut sehr sein. Allerdings sind Kombinationen mit "sau" und "schweine" recht geläufig, um eine Steigerung auszudrücken. Eben fällt mir zu "leise" aber noch "flüsterleise" ein. Das reiht sich viel besser in Kilians Vorschläge ein.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Der Wikipedia-Artikel zählt vier verschiedene Ausprägungen derselben Funktion als "Elativ" auf. Nur die vierte davon entspricht der angefragten Konstruktion, daher die Einschränkung auf *Präfix*-Elative